# How to share a given integer number and it's remainder across any number of people with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this current loop (it's not the real one bc can't share the real one, but the algorithm is the same):

```cs
class People {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }

    People() {
      this.name = '';
      this.quantity = 0;
    }

    People(string name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.quantity = 0;
    }
}

Class ItemShare {
    items_remaining = True;
    // Shared items counter
    q = 0; 

    public void share(int total_item_quantity, IEnumerable<People> people) {

        // If there's still items to be shared we begin to share them across people
        // until there are no items left
        while items_remaining{
            foreach People p in people {
                // adds 1 to counter
                q++ 
                // If counter is less or equal to tota quantity then we can still share 
                // that item to current person
                if (q <= total_item_quantity) {             
                    p.quantity++  // Increase quantity by 1
                } else {
                    // Turn off the flag, because there are no more items to be shared
                    items_remaining= False                     
                    break; // Break loop
                }
            }
        // Print results
        foreach p in People {
            Console.WriteLine($"name:{p.name} quantity: p.quantity")
        }
    }
}

...

static void main() {
    List<People> people = getPeopleFromDB();
    // It's just an integer variable from DB
    total_item_quantity = getQuantityFromDB(); 
    var c = new ItemShare();
    c.share(total_item_quantity, people);
}
```

**Result if people list contains 3 people and item_quantity is 20:**

- name: person1 quantity: 7
- name: person2 quantity: 7
- name: person3 quantity: 6

because 7 + 7 + 6 = 20

**Result if people list contains 3 people and item_quantity is 1:**

- name: person1 quantity:  1
- name: person2 quantity:  0
- name: person3 quantity:  0

because there's just 1 item total

**Result if people list contains 1 people and item_quantity is 5:**

- name: person1 quantity: 5

**Result if people list contains x people and item_quantity is y:**

?

Well, you get the idea...

As you can see i'm not asking how to do it, I've already done it.

I know how to share it equally, it's just a division: `[total_item_quantity / number of people in the people list]`.

It would be something like this:

```cs
quantity_between_people = Math.round(total_item_quantity / people.Count());

people.(select x=> { x.quantity = quantity_between_people; return x; })
```

But if you look carefully at the results list, you should take into account the remainder of the division. That's my problem. What I need to know is, if possible. How to do it in LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Math.DivRem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem?view=netcore-3.1) method to:

1. Get the quotient of `total_item_quantity` / `people.Count` and the remainder.
2. Get the number of persons who will receive the share.

First, let's revisit the `People` class.

```cs
namespace YourApp
{
    //...

    public class People
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int Quantity { get; set; } = 0;

        public People() { }

        public People(string name) => this.Name = name;

        public People(string name, int quantity)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Quantity = quantity;
        }

        public override string ToString() => $"{Name}, {Quantity}";
    }
```

Better to create an extension method for the `IEnumerable<People>` type to distribute the shares.

```cs
    static class Extensions
    {
        public static void Share(this IEnumerable<People> people, int amountToShare)
        {
            var div = Math.DivRem(amountToShare, people.Count(), out int rem);
            Math.DivRem(rem, people.Count(), out int maxPersons);

            people.Select((x, i) => {
                x.Quantity = div + (i < maxPersons ? 1 : 0); return x; }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Now your `main` should be something like this:

```cs
    static void Main()
    {
        var people = getPeopleFromDB();
        var total_item_quantity = getQuantityFromDB();

        people.Share(total_item_quantity);
        people.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
    }
}
```

Here's results of random tests:

```
Amount to share: 17
 Person 1, 6
 Person 2, 6
 Person 3, 5

Amount to share: 28
  Person 1, 4
  Person 2, 4
  Person 3, 4
  Person 4, 4
  Person 5, 4
  Person 6, 4
  Person 7, 4

Amount to share: 82
  Person 1, 14
  Person 2, 14
  Person 3, 14
  Person 4, 14
  Person 5, 13
  Person 6, 13
```

Comment: Wow, tt is realy clever. C# it's a very powerful language indeed Thank you very much, tat was almost a one liner. Marked as the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understood your question right, but as I can see from your code, you have an useless foreach loop at the end of the while loop.

You can place  `Console.WriteLine($"name:{p.Name} quantity: {p.Quantity}");` inside the if statement and avoid iterating through the list of people once more.

Here is how your method should probably look like:

```
public void share(int total_item_quantity, IEnumerable<People> people) 
{

    while (items_remaining)
                {
                    foreach (People p in people)
                    {
                        // adds 1 to counter
                        q++;

                        if (q <= total_item_quantity)
                        {
                            p.quantity++;  // Increase quantity by 1
                            Console.WriteLine($"name:{p.name} quantity: {p.quantity}");
                        }
                        else
                        {                           
                            items_remaining = false;
                            break; // Break loop
                        }
                    }
           }
}
```

Comment: that's not the problem the problem is to share a number between x objects including the remainder. Of course that for is useless...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code for exactly what you have been looking for. Very interesting problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Distribution
{
    class Program
    {
        public class People
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var totalQuantity = 5;
            var peoples = new List<string> { "John","Jack" };

            var count = peoples.Count();
            decimal quantityRaw = (decimal)totalQuantity / (decimal)count;
            int quantity = (int)Math.Ceiling(quantityRaw);

            var finalList = peoples.Select(x =>
            new People()
            {
                Name = x,
                Quantity = GetQuantity(quantity, totalQuantity, peoples.IndexOf(x))
            });

            foreach (var p in finalList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"name:{p.Name} quantity: {p.Quantity}");
            }
        }

        public static int GetQuantity(int qty, int qtyTotal, int idx)
        {
            return Math.Max(Math.Min(qtyTotal - qty * idx, qty), 0);
        }
    }

}
```